# Can I make a subdomain unresolvable despite presence of "search" in resolv.conf?

Tags: linux, dns, github, resolv.conf

I'm trying to find a workaround for the [known issue](https://enterprise.github.com/releases/2.7.5/notes) in Github Enterprise:

> We incorrectly redirect to the dashboard if you accessed GitHub
>   Enterprise using an alias while in private mode. This might happen if
>   you set a fully qualified domain name but the subdomain resolves
>   correctly.

Say I have Github hosted on `subdoma.in.example.com` and also have

```
search example.com
```

in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Is there any chance I can make `subdoma.in` non-resolvable?